# The order of the global Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, profinite-groups

For any profinite group $G$, we can define the order of $G$ using the notion of supernatural number. Now let $K$ be a number field, $S$ a finite set of primes of $K$ and $ G_{K,S} $ the Galois group of the maximal extension of $ K $ (inside a fixed algebraic closure of $K$) unramified outside $ S $. Let $G_{K,S}^{\text{ab}}$ denote the abelianization of the profinite group $G_{K,S}$. I am interested in the following questions:

1. Is it true that the order of $G_{K,S}^{\text{ab}}$ (as a supernatural number) is divisible only by finitely many primes?
2. Is it true that the order of $G_{K,S}$ (as a supernatural number) is divisible only by finitely many primes?
3. Suppose that the maximal pro-$ p $ quotient of $G_{K,S}$ is finite for any prime $p$. Is it true that the group $G_{K,S}$ is finite?

I guess the answer to question 1 is yes. It should be a corollary from CFT, but I can't find an exact description in the relevant literature. Regarding Question 3, the answer is no for general topologically finitely generated profinite groups.  For a counterexample, consider the profinite group $ G:=\prod_{p}C_{p} $ where the product runs over all primes $ p $ and $ C_{p} $ is the finite cyclic group of order $ p $. Then $G$ is an infinite topologically finitely gerated profinite group such that its maximal pro-$p$ quotient is finite for every $p$.

Comment: The answer to the question 1 and 2 are NO.

Comment: The answer to question 1 is YES. The only primes that can turn up are primes $p$ such that $p$ either divides $N(v)(N(v)-1)$ for $v \in S$ or divides the order of the class group of $K$.  Proof: $I_v$ is an inertia group at $v$, then $p$ divides $N(v)(N(v)-1)$ by considering what the abelian extensions of $K_v$ can be. Then the quotient of $G^{\mathrm{ab}}_{K,S}$ by all of the $I_v$ is the class group.

Comment: The answer to question 2 is NO. Take $K=\mathbf{Q}$ and $S = \{2,3\}$. The prime $2$ remains prime and unramified in $O:=\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{3^n}]$ for any $n$. The order of the ray class group of conductor $2$ is the order of the class group times the cokernel of the image of the global units in $(O/2O)^{\times}$. But the units are all either real or roots of unity, so the cokernel (up to powers of $3$ and $2$) is divisible by $q+1$, where the order of $O/2O$ is $q^2$ where $q = 2^{3^{n-1}}$. An elementary exercise shows that as $n$ increases $q+1$ is divisible by more and more primes.

Comment: For 3, I don't know any $K$ and a non-empty $S$ such that one can prove  $G_{K,S}$ is finite. So take $S = \emptyset$.  The strategy: find an imaginary quadratic field with cyclic class group so that the GS method applies to the Hilbert Class Field. For example $K = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-6883})$ has class group cyclic of degree $9$, but the degree $3$ unramified extension $L = \mathbf{Q}[x]/(x^6 - 2x^5 + 32x^4 - 68x^3 + 1998x^2 + 2868x + 2063)$ has class group containing $(\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^4$. I don't care enough to check if this example works, but something like this will.